# How many wives did Arjun have?

Tags: arjuna

I listen that Arjun has proposed to a woman to get marry but she refused.

Who was that woman refused to marry with Arjun and why?

How many wives did Arjun have? and who are they?

Comment: Subhadra & Draupadi are the most famous wives of Arjuna. However, during those time, whenever kings used to go for war or journey, they used to make wives on the way, using "GAndharva vivAha" (i.e. choosing partner due to mutual attraction or admiration). Then those women would bear children for those kings. e.g. Bhima had impregnated a Raksha woman named HidimbA, the mother of Ghatotkacha. Such marriages were not as revered as the ones which were made within Kshatriya clans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How many wives did Arjun have? and who are they?**

- Draupadi (princess of Panchal)
- Ulupi (princess of Nagaloka)
- Chitrangada (princess of Manipura)
- Subhadra (princess of Mathura/Dwarka)

I think no reference is needed for Draupadi and Subhadra. Other two are mentioned [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14080.htm).

**Note:** These are the only wives as per the original Mahabharata (written in Sanskrit), as per other versions of the Mahabharata, you may find more.

**Who was that woman refused to marry with Arjun and why?**

As per the original Mahabharata, it seems that you have reversed the question. It was Arjuna who refused [Matsya's princess](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/dutt/maha06.htm) and [Urvasi](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03046.htm). As per other versions of the Mahabharata, your question might be valid, you may read this from [here](http://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/mahabharata/2-of-5-the-other-wives.html).

Comment: But in your last link there is a line like "One of them was a warrior woman called Ali who refused to marry him but Arjuna was so besotted that he sought Krishna’s help"  so my question is valid, I think.

Comment: Yes but not in original Mahabharata..that is as per other versions of Mahabharata, I already mentioned that in my answer..this is same as Ur question abt Krishna-Arjuna battle which is not from original Mahabharata but from some other versions or as per books written based on Mahabharata..